# Search in last record of relationship - Laravel (Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, wherehas

i need to search in last record of an relationship in Laravel 7. Here is my code, hope u understand my question :)

```
$Collection = ServiceRequest::whereHas('ServiceRequestSignatureFlows', function ($query) use ($ou_id) {
                                           return $query->latest()->where('user_id',666);
                                           })
                                           ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
                                           ->get();
```

a ServiceRequest has many SignatureFlows, but i need only search on last flow inserted. I think that when i make ->latest(), my search could search 666 only in last rows, but doesnt happens.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can create the new relation `HasOne` and filter by it.

```
public function ServiceRequestSignatureLastFlow()
{
   return $this->hasOne(ServiceRequestSignatureFlows::class)->orderByDesc('id');
}
```

and than

```
$collection = ServiceRequest::whereHas('ServiceRequestSignatureLastFlow', function ($query) use ($ou_id) {
        $query->where('user_id', $ou_id);
    })->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return` inside the `whereHas`